# Host a mvc application in a console application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, hosting

I have a peace of software that is installed on clients, and these need an interactive webpage to modify and read out data, so the clients can be configurated over the network. now i have looked at mvc, and this seems to be able to do exactly this, but i need the webpage to be hosted from my other software application so i can send and receive date directly to the running software. so in principle my software starts up, and alows people to open an interactive website when going to the ipaddress of that client. and from there thay can modify propertys and so on.

---

So the problem is: is it possible and how, to host an mvc build website on existing software?

Comment: @oleksii, Im new in mvc but how can i acces my other application via the 'HomeController'?

Comment: what do you mean under access? If you have a console app that hosts an mvc project, you first start it (it then becomes effectively a web server). By then you should know which IP address (localhost maybe) and port (80 if nothing else listens on that port) it runs on. So you can go to browser or another application then send requests and can start talking to your mvc application as if it was hosted elsewhere (for example you can navigate to http://localhost:80)

Answer (score 0):

Werner Strydom said:
You can use "IIS 7.0 Hostable Web Core" and host the web server as part of any user process, even a console application. The benefit is that it is very similar to full blown IIS (incl config etc) but the web server itself is running in your process.

Have a look at the following articles:
1.Host your own Web Server in your application using IIS 7.0 Hostable Web Core
2.Creating Hosted Web Core Applications